# Sed. How to remove line match with pattern and strings arround it?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file where you want to delete line matching by pattern and remove strings above and below.

By example:

`FFFFIFIBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBFBBBBFBBBB77<<BBBBBB7B<BBBBBB<B<
    @HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:13002:2147 1:N:0:CTGT
    GATCCCCGTCTATCAGATACACGTTACTCAGCTAGTGCGAATGCGAACGCGAAATTTT
    +
    FFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFFFBFFFBFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFBFB
    @HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:15368:2194 1:N:0:CTGT
    +
    FFIFBFFIFFBBBFFFFFFFBBFFBFFBBBFFFBB7BBBBBBFFFBB700<7770<BBB0<0<BFFBFBFFFFF
    @HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:19167:2169 1:N:0:CTGT
    GATCTCATATAGGGCAGCGTGGTCGCGGC`

I want to remove second block which does not contain the nucleotide sequence.

The end result:

```
`FFFFIFIBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBFBBBBFBBBB77<<BBBBBB7B<BBBBBB<B<
@HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:13002:2147 1:N:0:CTGT
GATCCCCGTCTATCAGATACACGTTACTCAGCTAGTGCGAATGCGAACGCGAAATTTT
+
FFIFBFFIFFBBBFFFFFFFBBFFBFFBBBFFFBB7BBBBBBFFFBB700<7770<BBB0<0<BFFBFBFFFFF
@HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:19167:2169 1:N:0:CTGT
GATCTCATATAGGGCAGCGTGGTCGCGGC
`
```

Pattern which matched this block

```
'^.+$(\n)^(@HISEQ).*$(\n)^\+'
```

works in **perl** and **javascript**, but not **sed**.

Because **sed** does not work with line break.

I found the solution

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /' test
```

But this code replace line break to space. If insert to this code my regexp:

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;/^.+$(\n)^(@HISEQ).*$(\n)^\+/d' test
```

this does not work.
Can you help me find the solution of this problem?

---

I'm just stupid. I misunderstood the file format. 
Input:

```
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:1309:1956 1:N:0:ACAGTGA 
+ 
JJJHIIJFIJJJJ=BFFFFFEEEEEEDDDDDDDDDDBD 
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:3437:1952 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

How to edit the regular exp to get what you want

output:

```
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:3437:1952 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

Comment: `sed` works on one line at a time. It would probably be better to use `awk` or `perl`, which allow you to deal with larger blocks more easily.

Comment: What do you mean "replace caret to space"? There are no carets in your file.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I mean line break, not carets

Comment: A better regex using no modifiers would be `.+$\r?\n@HISEQ.*$\r?\n\+\s*`

Comment: `awk` it so difficult for me. I don't understand the awk logic.

Comment: You don't understand awk logic but you're fine with `sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;/^.+$(\n)^(@HISEQ).*$(\n)^\+/d' test`??? Crazy... Awk could not be simpler - it's just an Algol-based programming language like most you are probably familiar with, but with a few enhancements for manipulating text. Seriously - try it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then

```
sed ':loop; N; /\n+/ ! { $ ! b loop }; /\n@HISEQ[^\n]\+\n+/ d' foo.txt
```

will work. This is as follows:

```
:loop                    # in a loop
N                        # fetch more lines
/\n+/ ! { $ ! b loop }   # until one starts with + or is the last line
/\n@HISEQ[^\n]\+\n+/ d   # if the penultimate line of all that begins with @HISEQ,
                         # discard the lot.
```

That last pattern is using the fact that it is checked right after the first line that begins with `+` is found, so the `\n+` at the end of it uniquely matches the start of the last line in the block.

Comment: You are a magician! This is what you need! Could you tell me where I can read about the loops and cycles in sed

Comment: Whenever I need to look up sed stuff, I go [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Comment: I am still looking at this carefully...ha!..+1

Answer (score 3):

To remove the second block, you can just do:

```
awk 'NR!=2' RS=+ ORS=+ input
```

But I would suspect you want something more like:

```
awk '/[GATC]{5,}\n/' RS=+ ORS=+ input
```

or

```
awk '/\n[GATC]*\n/' RS=+ ORS=+ input
```

Comment: `RS=+` means the Record Separator is the character `+`. I assume you were confused by `+` being an RE metacharacter but it's not that in this context (ie. when it's the first char in a string).

Comment: Also, note that using any string longer than one character for RS is not standard awk.  gnu awk allows RS to be an arbitrary regular expression (I think), but using a string longer than one character is left undefined by the language itself (most implementations either treat it as a regex or truncate it and use only the first character.)

Answer (score 2):

Easier to do this parsing using `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=+ -v ORS=+ '!/\n@HISEQ[^\n]*\n$/' file
FFFFIFIBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBFBBBBFBBBB77<<BBBBBB7B<BBBBBB<B<7BBBBFFFBBBBFBBBBBBBFBFFFFB<<
@HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:13002:2147 1:N:0:CTGT
GATCCCCGTCTATCAGATACACGTTACTCAGCTAGTGCGAATGCGAACGCGAAATTTT
+
FFIFBFFIFFBBBFFFFFFFBBFFBFFBBBFFFBB7BBBBBBFFFBB700<7770<BBB0<0<BFFBFBFFFFF<B<7<<BBBBFB0
@HISEQ:102:h9u5badxx:1:1101:19167:2169 1:N:0:CTGT
GATCTCATATAGGGCAGCGTGGTCGCGGC
+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed '/FFFFFFFFBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFFFBFFFBFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFBFB/,/\+/ d' YourFile
```

should be enough