# Sed. remove multiline patterns. RegExp

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have fastq file with strict formatting.

Input file:

```
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:1309:1956 1:N:0:ACAGTGA 
+ 
JJJHIIJFIJJJJ=BFFFFFEEEEEEDDDDDDDDDDBD 
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:3437:1952 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

In my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804541/sed-how-to-remove-line-match-with-pattern-and-strings-arround-it#comment44018227_27804541) I solved my problem. But I do not correctly understand the file format. I need to get from input file this file:

output:

```
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:3437:1952 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

Where I remove read who isn't contain sequence.

This script works correctly. But i don't write regular expression to get what you want

```
awk '/\n[GATC]*\n/' RS=+ ORS=+
```

after script work I expected to see this [output file](http://pastebin.com/byXewJaU). By this [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/yM1mK0/1) you will see expression that describes the rows that I want to delete.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what lang and what regexp to use to remove multiline pattern from input file?

Comment: As long as you keep using sed for problems that span multiple lines you will keep having to completely rewrite it every time you have the tiniest change in requirements and you will probably have to keep asking for help to do so. All of those wacky, archane, single-character sed constructs for handling multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. This is the job awk (which is record-oriented, not line-oriented) was invented to do - just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^@H/ { N; /\n+$/ { N; d } }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/^@H/ {     # if the current line begins with @H
  N         # fetch the next one, append it.
  /\n+$/ {  # if the combined pattern has \n+ at the end (that is, if the new 
            # line is "+")
    N       # fetch another line
    d       # and discard the lot.
  }
}
```

Comment: You help me for the second time. Thank you very much! I am in your debt.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl.

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/[GATC]+\h*\n\K\+.*?[GATC]+\n//gs' file
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:1309:1956 1:N:0:ACAGTGA 
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

But this leaves the spaces at the last untouched. If you want to remove also the trailing spaces then try the below.

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/[GATC]+\K\h*\n\+.*?[GATC]+\n/\n/gs' file
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:1309:1956 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA 
+ 
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to know how the command they already have worked.

Comment: Ok. I have this input  [file](http://pastebin.com/CFJq6kGg). When I apply your script to file, I get this output [file](http://pastebin.com/Pgj6NJDk). How to solve this problem?

Comment: could you provide the expected output for half of your input? So that i would get an idea for more than one sequence.

Comment: after script work I expected to see this output [file](http://pastebin.com/byXewJaU). By this [link](https://www.regex101.com/r/yM1mK0/1) you will see expression that describes the rows that I want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/(^|\n)@[^\n]+\n\+\n[^\n]+\n/,"")}1' file
@HWI-ST383:199:D1L73ACXX:3:1101:3437:1952 1:N:0:ACAGTGA
GATCTCGAAGCAAGAGTACGACGAGTCGGGCCCCTCCA
+
IIIIFFF<?6?FAFEC@=C@1AE###############
```

i.e. just delete any string that starts with "@" (`(^|\n)@`) then a bunch of non-newline chars (`[^\n]+`) then a `+` between newlines (`\n\+\n`) then a bunch of other non-newline chars terminated with a newline (`[^\n]+\n`). If any lines can have leading or trailing whitespace then just throw a `[[:blank:]]*` in wherever the white space could occur.